# How do I show this is an isometry relating to First Fundamental Form?

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

If I have a function $f(z) = \frac{z-i}{z + i}$, with $f: \Bbb{H} \to \Bbb{D}$ and the First Fundamental Form coefficients of each space ($\Bbb H$ and $\Bbb D$) given, how can I show that f is an isometry between $\Bbb H$ and $\Bbb D$?

Here z is standard, i.e   z = u + iv.

$ \Bbb D := \{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$

$ \Bbb H$ is the  hyperbolic plane with $(u,v) \in \Bbb R \times (0,\infty)$

Comment: What are $\Bbb{H}$ and $\Bbb{D}$?

Comment: @Cuhrazatee I've updated the question, thank you for answering

Comment: Just show that the differential of $f$ brings the metric on $H$ onto the metric on $D$.

Comment: @DIdier_ How exactly would I go about that?

Comment: By computing the differential of $f$ maybe?

Comment: First, you need the Poincaré metric on $\Bbb D$, not the usual metric. Second, you need to know how to pull back $dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy$.